# how to get height of event while setting the content in eventContent for fullcalendar v5

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

how we can get height of event while setting the content in eventContent for fullcalendar v5.
i have checked the code and it is generated automatically, but i want to get the height at  eventContent to hide/show info depending on height.

Answer (score 0):

Make a hook on
"eventDidMount" :
[link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks)

an search in arg.el for the item.

```
arg.el.find(".fc-title")  // jQuery, geht aber auch ohne
```

get the height

```
.height()  // jQuery, geht aber auch ohne
```

Summary:

```
eventDidMount:function(argE) { 
    h = arg.el.find(".fc-title").height(); 
    if(typeof(h) != "undefined") {
       if (h > 20) {
       // ... your code
       }
    }
    return (argE.event._def.title;); // dont forget the reason for this hook
},  // <= das Komma für die Liste nicht vergessen
```